# What does ところ in the paragraph below mean?

Tags: grammar

> 三村株式会社より、「はさみSB—A」に欠陥が発見されたため全製品を回収し、交換を行うとの発表がありました。
> **会計課で調べたところ購入記録がありましたので、三村株式会社に交換を依頼します。**

I looked it up in the 大辞泉 dictionary and found a sentence that looked like this:

> 調べたところでは、そんな事実はない

The dictionary tells me that ところ indicates 程度 in the sentence above, but I don't know whether it is the same usage as the sentence in my paragraph. Even if it is the same usage, it is also difficult for me to understand what 会計課で調べたところ購入記録 means.

Answer (score 1):

ところ makes an adverbial clause here, so you can think では is omitted.

- 会計課で調べたところでは、購入記録がありました
- As the account dept looked up, there was a purchase record.

[This J-E dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%89%80/#je-54381) says that kind of ところ means *when*, which should be practical enough. As for the [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%89%80_%28%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%29/#jn-158611) (2-キ), the usage is more 範囲: *to the extent/as far as the dept looked up,...*